# Have a Ford F250 6.7 superduty 2011 want to change the serpentine belt but having trouble getting the connector to the fan

Tags: ford, connector, f-250

Ford F250 super duty 2011. need to disconnect connector to the fan in order to change the serpentine belt.  Do not know how to disconnect this connector. Help

Comment: I'm not clear why you need to get to the fan connector.  Just disconnect the (-) battery cable.

Comment: The serpentine belt goes around this wire harness that connects to the fan, it has to be disconnected to put on the new belt.

Comment: A picture of the harness and connector might be useful. Attach it to your question by using the "Edit" button, and then the "Moon and Mountains" button.